# App.vue is not working in Vue-Native application

Tags: react-native, vue.js, vue-native

i initialize project with 
vue-native init projectname 
after initializing there is "app.js" and "app.vue" file in the project and every time i run my application it only run the app.js file while the vue file is ignored.. any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

If you use `expo`, you must find file: `your-app/node-modules/expo(not @expo but expo)/AppEntry.js` and change import App from `'../../App';` to import App from `'../../App.vue';`